# Разрывание слов в тексте при вставке строки

Tags: php

Столкнулся с проблемой разрыва слов в тексте при вставке определённой строки.
Тоесть есть текст, с помощью одной функции(**substr**)разрывается текст наполовину, кладется в переменную(кстати используется рандом для вставки в случайном месте и из-за этого получается не то что нужно).Почти таким образом ещё получается вторая часть. Потом все это собирается вместе.Понятное дело что при делении текста на две части случайно делится одно из слов,а потом сама строка вставляется в данный разрыв. *Вот сам скрипт* :

```
<?php

$text = 'наш любимый текст текст текст';
$good = strlen($text);
$ran = rand(0,$good);
$string = " <b>Скачать чит</b> ";
$text1 = substr ($text, 0,$ran);
$text2 = substr ($text, $ran);
echo $text1 .    $string   .  $text2;
?>
```

Comment: Если вы ищите на вопрос "как разделить строку не в середине слова", то, очевидно, необходимо делить ее по пробелу.

Comment: пересмотрите лучший ответ - @Deonis предоставил более компактный вариант

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
$text = 'наш любимый текст текст текст';
$string = " <b>Скачать чит</b> ";
$mid_pos = mb_strpos($text, ' ', rand(0,mb_strlen($text)));
echo mb_substr($text, 0,  $mid_pos) , $string  , mb_substr($text, $mid_pos);
```

Comment: самый лучший вариант как по мне! голоса закончились

Answer (score 0):

Похоже, что вам нужно сначала разбивать исходный текст на слова, а затем проводить манипуляции со словами, а не с символами. Например так:

```
$text = 'наш любимый текст текст текст';
$string = " <b>Скачать чит</b> ";

$words = expolde(' ', $text);
$ran = rand(0, count($words));
$text1 = implode(' ', array_slice($words, 0, $ran));
$text2 = implode(' ', array_slice($words, $ran));

echo $text1 . $string . $text2;
```

Answer (score 0):

ну и свой вариант выкину, раз написал

```
<?php

$text = 'aaaa bbbb cccc dddd eeee';
$string = " <b>xxx</b> ";

$mas = explode(" ", $text);
$ran = rand(0,count($mas));
array_splice($mas, $ran , 0, $string);
$text =implode(" ", $mas);
var_dump($text);
```